# Apache 2.4 expr - how to load a html file via RewriteRule?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite

On Apache 2.4, Having a bunch of mixed SEO friendly and dynamic URLs on an ecom site I want to implement a simple caching system for my blog posts and product pages. First I want to have md5(REQUEST_URI+QUERY_STRING) and then load the prerendered /cache/md5hashumfile.html that's all.

Here is my htaccess code:

```
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteBase /subfolder/
    RewriteCond "expr=%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/cache/%{md5:%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}}\.html" -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cache/%{md5:%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}}\.html [L]
```

When I do

```
Header set foo-doc-root "expr=%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/cache/%{md5:%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}}\.html"
#Outputs
foo-doc-root:   /home/user/public_html/subfolder/cache/f427ac3f86b93f6869ef8c2ce847dbd6.html
```

I can verify in my headers the path is correct and the file exists exactly where I expect it.

I can verify the md5 sum of my URL been the same md5

```
Header set foo-uri "expr=%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}\.html"
```

Where can it be improved?

Comment: "Where can it be improved?" - But I assume it's not working at all at present?

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not.

Comment: In the RewriteCond I think I would capture the specific parts instead of repeating the same expression in the rewriterule . `RewriteCond "expr=%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/(cache/%{md5:%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}}\.html)" -f` and then `RewriteRule ^   /%1 [L]`

Comment: @DanielFerradal I think that's the right idea (you can't use _expressions_ in the `RewriteRule` anyway). However, there are some more fundamental errors here . The syntax for using expressions in a `RewriteCond` directive is not correct and I don't believe you can create arbitrary capturing groups like this - this is a regex _thing_, so a separate regex-condition is required to simply capture the result of the `md5()` function. I've explained some of this in [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1127451/49157).

Comment: Just curious... at what point do you create the cache file? (How do you expire/delete the cache?)

Comment: As always, it is a pleasure to read your comments and answers @MrWhite. I should have been more specific that my comment wasn't aiming for a perfectly correct answer but a hint to a more correct approach. Thanks for your comments and answer, very specific and on point. Cheers!

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for your comments and answer. I will try your code later today. As you can see my strength isn't server/htaccess. About the Cache, I will capture the page using curl with specific http headers/user-agent for mobile, and one for desktop. We have one language and one currency at the moment, so for now I won't dig deeper than that. The script encapsulated in a model->method, will be run on product-edit event and separately via cron to reflect stock/price changes (ERP integration) 3 times a day. Separate cron for cleanup, that's it.  I want to serve this for no-cookies requests.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteBase /subfolder/
> RewriteCond "expr=%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/cache/%{md5:%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}}\.html" -f 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cache/%{md5:%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}}\.html [L]
> ```

You have a few errors here:

- You are setting `RewriteBase /subfolder/`, however, this is not being used  by this rule since you are using a root-relative *substitution* string (starting with a slash). Consequently, it looks like you are trying to rewrite to the wrong URL-path. ie. `/cache/...` instead of `/subfolder/cache/...`. EDIT: I assume this rule is being used in a *directory* (or `.htaccess`) context, otherwise the use of `RewriteBase` here is wholly invalid.
- `RewriteCond "expr=` - This is not the correct syntax when using an Apache expression inside a `RewriteCond` directive. It looks like you are using mod_headers syntax. With mod_rewrite the *TestString* (1st argument) should be `expr`, then the *CondPattern* (2nd argument) is the *expression*. eg. `RewriteCond expr expression`.
- `-f` (at the end) - Again, this is not the correct syntax. When using an *Apache expression*, the `-f` operator is part of the expression (*CondPattern*) and must come first. (Ordinarily, when using normal mod_rewrite syntax, the `-f` "test" is the *CondPattern* itself.)
- You can't use expression syntax in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string. You can, however, use backreferences to captured groups (regex) in the preceding *conditions*. So, calculate/capture the md5 hash in a *condition* and use a backreference instead.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteCond expr "-f '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/cache/%{md5:%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}}.html'"
RewriteCond expr "'cache/%{md5:%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}}.html' =~ /(.+)/"
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L]
```

Additional notes:

- `^(.*)$` - No need to captured the URL-path since you are using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead.
- No need to backslash-escape literal dots in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string - this is an "ordinary string", not a regex.
- I've removed the slash prefix from the *substitution* string so that it will now take into account the `RewriteBase`.
- The purpose of the 2nd `RewriteCond` directive is simply to capture the md5 hash file name (and file-path) to then use in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* using the `%1` backreference.

The above does require two calls to the `md5()` function. You could try the
following instead to reduce this to one (and to also remove the dependency on `RewriteBase`, since you are having to hardcode the `/subfolder` in the expression anyway):

```
RewriteCond expr "'/subfolder/cache/%{md5:%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}}.html' =~ /(.+)/"
RewriteCond expr "-f '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1'"
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L]
```